# Mikrotik router Layer7 regexp block access by DNS zones

Tags: regex, dns, mikrotik

I trying to make regex for block resources with specific DNS zones only
for example .ru

I tried several regex but something Mikrotik router specific and expressions not work...

This list of patterns not work and I not understand why, because in online test tools all work...

```
^.+(\.ru\/|\.ru$).*$
(\^*.ru$|\^*.ru\/)
^.+(\^*.ru$|\^*.ru\/).*$
^.+(\.ru$|\.ru\/).*$
^(.*ru\/.*|.*ru$.*)$
```

https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:Regular_Expressions

https://rubular.com/r/7wS6i3pi6pxJdI

I need help to find what's wrong with expressions in my list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex in mikrotik is a bit simplified, not everything works unfortunately

The solution to your problem:

Regexp:

```
(\.ru$)|(\.ru\.)
```

Mikrotik Telminal:

```
/ip dns static add address=1.1.1.1 regexp="(\\.ru$)|(\\.ru\\.)"
```

WinBox:

[image]